# PostgreSQL: Drop DB which exits with no parameters

Tags: postgresql

I am trying from 3 days to drop the 'test123' DB which is not getting drop. Postgres reply of no such db exists.. i have no idea how it listed like this. and the db with \r

```
template1=# select * from pg_database;
        datname        | datdba | encoding | datcollate  |  datctype   | datistemplate | datallowconn | datconnlimit | datlastsysoid | datfrozenxid | dattablespace |               datacl                
-----------------------+--------+----------+-------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+-------------------------------------
 template1             |     10 |        6 | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | t             | t            |           -1 |         12035 |          709 |          1663 | {=c/postgres,postgres=CTc/postgres}
 template0             |     10 |        6 | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | t             | f            |           -1 |         12035 |          709 |          1663 | {=c/postgres,postgres=CTc/postgres}
 postgres              |     10 |        6 | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | f             | t            |           -1 |         12035 |          709 |          1663 | 
 PremierSuppliers      |  16384 |        6 | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | f             | t            |           -1 |         12035 |          709 |          1663 | 
 \r                   +|  16384 |        6 | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | f             | t            |           -1 |         12035 |          709 |          1663 | 
 test123               |        |          |             |             |               |              |              |               |              |               |
```

Any workaround solution? to drop \r and test123 .  i need to know what is the '+' placed in \r  . and how to drop it. just to let you know that i already tried the steps given for similiar issue [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12676/dropped-database-still-shows-but-causes-errors-postgresql) but my problem not resolved.

Comment: I think you have one database called `\r...test123` (where `...` are a bunch of spaces) or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic database name seems to consist of a carriage return (ASCII code 13, shown as `\r`) followed by a newline (ASCII code 10) followed by the string `test123`

The sequence of characters 13,10 is the end of line in Windows.

The `+` sign at the end of the column is added by psql as a visual indication that the column continues on the next line. It's not part of the database name.

You may confirm the exact character codes by issuing:

```
SELECT encode(datname::bytea,'hex') from pg_database where datname like '%test123';
```

The expected result would be `0d0a74657374313233` if there are no spaces in addition to the CRLF. (otherwise please update the question with the actual result).

If using `psql` in Unix with readline capabilities, you may drop the database with this sequence of keystrokes:

DROP DATABASE "<kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>test123";<kbd>Enter</kbd>

When hitting <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd> the screen should display `^M`

**EDIT**:

If you can't manage it within `psql` in interactive mode, as an alternative this should also work from bash, to be launched by the postgres user or the database owner:

```
echo -e "DROP DATABASE \"\r\ntest123\";" | psql -d template1
```

The `-e` option to `echo` enables the interpretation of backslash escapes.

Comment: I really appreciate you for the help.  Yes the expect result of SELECT command was indeed shows

template1=# SELECT encode(datname::bytea,'hex') from pg_database where datname like '%test123';
       encode       
--------------------
 0d0a74657374313233
(1 row)

In order to drop DB, i.e pressing ctrl+V ctrl+M i see it display ^M

template1=# DROP DATABASE "^M

ENTER , it seems screen goes to new one. 

template1"#

Can you pls suggest how to drop it and how to know if psql in linux enable with readline capablilies. Excuse me for this questions as i m in learning stage on postgresql.

Comment: @Johnbritto: if _screen goes to new one_ means it goes to the next line, that's fine. Continue typing the rest of the keystrokes and hit Enter after the `;` terminating the command. Then it should display `DROP DATABASE` and the db will be gone.

Comment: Great, thanks u so much. it solved the issue.  test123 is no more.. could you please educate what might be the cause of such database creation and getting locked. i think one of my dev would have commited this mistake unknowingly.

Comment: @Johnbritto: the CR,LF sequence suggests a Windows program with a multiline input field for the database name, but that's speculation.